# Get sum from a custom table column value in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get  sum of a column named `earned` from  my custom table `share`.

For this I have written following code but its showing an `ARRAY` text as result output. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 

$username = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
$cc=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT sum(earned) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."share WHERE user = '$username' ");
echo $cc;

?>
```

Comment: instead of echo, use var_dump($cc); and you'll see that the result of your query is array; than just use this var.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this use `$wpdb->get_var`:

```
$cc = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT sum(earned) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."share WHERE user = '$username' " );
echo $cc;
```

You can find more information [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable).